# Storing event-messages in a SQL-Server table

Tags: c#, events, asp.net-web-api, message, stomp

I have a Web API that creates a purchase order.
Once this purchase order is created I have to acknowledge the creation to another 3rd party web service through that service's API call.

At the point of successful order creation, I want to store the - events/messages - to call the 3rd part API in a Sql Server Table.
I am inclined to store these in the STOMP/STOMP-like format.

Eventually, I will have another worker wade through all the stored events in the table and fire the respective handlers to communicate with the subscribers.

How do I store these events in the most efficient manner in the database?

NOTE: I do not intend to use a real message queue, for now. And I do not want synchronous events to be raised to call the 3rd party API either.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't want to have the table schema match the message parameters, right?  Maybe there are a lot of different message types or they are subject to change.  Then really your only option is to serialize it one way or another.  JSON is one way to go, but depending on the data types might require more storage than you want.  Some kind of binary encoding would be more efficient, but sacrifices human-readability.